# Variable named range cell references in Queries

Tags: google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

1. The primary sheet has one column with dates; and thousands of rows on this sheet.
2. There are hundreds of other sheets, named by date.  The format of each of these other date sheets is identical.
3. I need a query that can use each date on the primary sheet as reference to query a corresponding date sheet.
4. I would like to drag this formula down across all rows, and have the formula ref the date in the row rather than manually enter each cell.
5. Since I can't name the date sheets by date alone, I will need a naming formula that adds a word to the dates.
6. I've tried applying Named-Ranges to the date sheets and referencing them in the cells with import-range, but this did not work.  I also tried inserting a link to the named ranges in each date cell, but this did not work either.
7. I've attached a screen grab of the idea.  The data is just for illustration, it is fake.  Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to this, experimented, researched, could not find a solution.  Thanks!

[image: sample]

Comment: share a copy of your fake sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({INDIRECT("C"&ROW(C8)&"!A:H")}, 
 "select Col5,Col8 
  where Col3 > date '"&TEXT(C8, "yyyy-mm-dd)&"' 
    and Col4 = 'SALE'
    and Col5 <= "&D8 + (D8*E8)&"
    and Col8 < 1
    and Col8 > 0.01
  order by Col8
  limit 1", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Here is the formula I got to work... I combined it with another answer you gave on the Sheet Name Source query.  One more question... I had to add a Link to the Named Range on the other sheet in the cell ref.  How to do that automatically for a thousand cells, each pointing to a different sheet & named range by date?  =QUERY(INDIRECT(C3&"!A2:H20"), "select E, G  
  where C > date '"&TEXT(C3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  
    and D = 'CALL'  
    and E <= "& D3 + (D3 * E3)&"  
    and G < 1  
    and G > 0.01  
  order by G  
  limit 1", 0)

Comment: not sure I understand your followup question. can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: Sure: originally Cell C3 just had a date inside, which matched the title of a sheet.  The formula did not work with just the date/title.  So I added a link in cell C3 to the Named Range within the ref sheet.  It would be very difficult to add thousands of different links to the different dates on my master sheet.  Is there a way to automatically add the links to all dates in a column, so that x date=x sheet?

Comment: Nevermind!  Just solved it.  Just needed to add a link to the date cell, not the named range.  When I deleted the unique link to the named range and only kept the "link" to the date, it still works.  Very straightforward.  Thank you for your help!